# Process: com.android.packageinstaller OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, error-handling, out-of-memory

I generated my application APK file.
now, when im trying to open it via my device, im getting :

```
5474-5474/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.packageinstaller, PID: 5474
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2150)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:715)
            at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getAppSnippet(PackageUtil.java:181)
            at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.initView(InstallAppProgress.java:248)
            at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.onCreate(InstallAppProgress.java:182)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please please help me...
what did I do wrong?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549232/outofmemory-recycle-images/27555881#27555881

Comment: Thank you !
It seems that the problem was pretty simple, the icon Image was to big....

Answer (score 1):

Android allocates 4 bytes per pixel for the image. Add to that the fact that if the icon is in drawable, android allocates additional resources to scale it up.

Android would also have limitations on how much memory it can allocate to the icon while installing the app. If the icon is too big, the app will run out of memory.

Solution - Follow the icon design guidelines [here for adaptive](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html) or [here for legacy](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#). If you don't want to go into the complexities, just reduce your icon size and your app will work.