# load part of a big data into memory

Tags: android

I have a big String data in a SQLite database. When I load it like below

```
Database database=new Database(MainActivity.this);
String data=database.getString(2);
```

gives Out of Memory Exception. So I decided to load half of database.getString(2) into memory, But I don't know How can I do it.

I setted `largeHeap=true` in manifest.

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549232/outofmemory-recycle-images/27555881#27555881