# Out Of Memory In XML-RPC result

Tags: java, android

I have a Web service based on XML-RPC ,I tried to download a large data using this method :

```
byte[] data = request.getInfo(infoFilter).getDocuments().get(indexDocument).getContent();
```

When the data is considered as big, the application will cause exception of out of memory ,because some device has a small size cache ,my solution here is to truncate the data in small quantity. I think I need to get inspiref from this code :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write(current);
}
fos.close();
```

Can anyone has an idea about how can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is `request` ? is this an object from a 3rd pary lib or do you have full source code control over this class ?

Comment: is the part of 3rd library , i dont have a full source code control

Comment: If there is no special parameter or similiar control for `getContent()` to limit the amount per request, I think you are out of luck. Could you write your own XML-RPC for a specific case ?

Comment: Look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549232/outofmemory-recycle-images/27555881#27555881

Comment: @PeterMmm i have a flags to activate the download of data or not  , but a special parameter to  to limit the amount per request dosent exist , i will talk the creator of the library to give me another way to download the data per amount . thanks Peter